# what is the use of PLI keyword?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

while writing some stored procedures in ms sql 2008, as I was typing some variable names I noticed that PLI was highlighted as a keyword.

Does anyone have any idea what PLI is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this type of information on MSDN:

Please see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125948

Answer (score 0):

`PLI` is a reference to the programming language [PL/I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I). It is a keyword in the [SQL-99 `MODULE` statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/module-statement/) used to indicate that the PL/I programming language is expected to call a SQL-client module (and thus which calling conventions the SQL-client module must support.) Now, SQL Server does not support the `MODULE` statement, so why would be this marked as a keyword? I can only speculate, but a likely reason is they wanted to leave their options open if they ever decided to implement this syntax in the future.